# Does Akka-Alpakka Ftp library support to get file from URL?

Tags: ftp, akka, akka-stream, java.nio.file

I'm using https://github.com/akka/alpakka/tree/master/ftp/src this library for Ftp client. I have the url of the file as a path. But as I see from the code implementation, they support only java.nio.file.Path in the function.

```
val ftpSettings = FtpSettings(host, port, NonAnonFtpCredentials(userName, pass), passiveMode = true)
Ftp.fromPath("Path object", ftpSettings)
```

But I don't have a local file. I have only url for the file. Is there a possibility to get the file via url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 more overloads of `fromPath` that allow to specify host and credentials.

```
  def fromPath(
      host: String,
      path: Path
  )(implicit ftpLike: FtpLike[FtpClient]): Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]]

  def fromPath(
      host: String,
      username: String,
      password: String,
      path: Path
  )(implicit ftpLike: FtpLike[FtpClient]): Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]]
```

Comment: I'm already using this settings.

val ftpSettings = FtpSettings(host, port, NonAnonFtpCredentials(userName, pass))

Both of the functions wait a Path param.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I found the usage of path with urls. Instead of using the whole url, just use the path of the file.

```
Ftp.fromPath(Paths.get("/directory/fileName.txt"), ftpSettings)
```